# An issue with matching a simple regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem matching regex in Java, my text is:

> Temperature: 9°C (48°F), Wind Direction: South South Westerly, Wind
>   Speed: 19mph, Humidity: 87%, Pressure: 1018mb, Rising, Visibility:
>   Good

My regex is

```
\bTemperature:[^,]*
```

The matching code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\bTemperature:[^,]*");

    Matcher m = p.matcher("Temperature: 10°C (50°F), Wind Direction: South South Easterly, Wind Speed: 25mph, Humidity: 78%, Pressure: 1014mb, Falling, Visibility: Good");

    if(m.find())
    {
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }

  }
}
```

It does not output anything.

Answer (score 4):

Try use `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bTemperature:[^,]*");` to escape.

As user John Bollinger said in the comment:

> You need a backslash to be read and interpreted by the Pattern class,
>   but backslashes in string literals are subject to interpretation by
>   the Java compiler. The compiler converts a doubled backslash to a
>   single backslash, just as Pattern requires.

The two backslashes will be compiled as one.

So when you reading the regex pattern string from file or console, you just need one backslash.

Comment: To clarify: you need a backslash to be read and interpreted by the `Pattern` class, but backslashes in string literals are subject to interpretation by the Java compiler.  The compiler converts a doubled backslash to a single backslash, just as `Pattern` requires.